# Extracting HTML tag from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like 
"For more information, go to google"

When I directly put this string inside a span in my razor (cshtml) view, I get the raw string in the DOM. How can I make it behave like HTML content, i.e. text followed by a link? Is there any way other than parsing the string and extracting the href and link text and then putting them inside a new anchor tag?

Comment: Yah for sure… start coding :-)

Comment: Why you hunting for another way? Are you facing any problem or difficulty with **parsing the string and extracting the href and link text and then putting them inside a new anchor tag** ?